# JFrame is lagging on resize

Tags: macos, jframe, java, lag

Im having a simple JFrame which draws a background color. But when i resize the window, the background color is somehow lagging, as you can see in the screenshot. Is there a way to prevent this issue?

```
public class ToolBarTest extends JFrame{
    public ToolBarTest(){
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(221,221,221));
        setSize(400,250);
        setTitle("Hello");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String ... args){
        new ToolBarTest().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

**SOLUTION:**
Remove JVM and JDK 7 and reinstall java 6.
Conclusion: dont use java 7 on mac os. (?)

Comment: Does it actually fill to expand the window after a certain amount of time or does the background just remain that size regardless of how much resizing takes place?

Comment: it fills the whole window again. it kinda lags a few milliseconds behind...

Comment: Have you tried placing a panel with the background into the frame? I wasn't able to duplicate the issue you're having, so it may be hardware related.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Quaqua. Again, not working properly on Lion, Snow Leopard, no problem... 
So do i just need to install an older version of the JRE?

[image]

**EDIT:**
It is indeed the JRE 7. I updated My Desktop Lion 10.7, which was still using Java 6 – now its lagging too. I mean, this sucks big time...