# apple.awt.brushMetalLook weird behaviour on mac 10.7 retina

Tags: java, macos, jvm, retina-display, look-and-feel

I'm using a 10.7.4 Retina. My JFrame doesn't look as expected when I'm using `getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.brushMetalLook", true);`
I tried running it on the JVM 1.6.0_51. It will look like this:
[image]

Even tried it with -d32 and -d64.

And when I'm running it on the latest JVM 1.7.0_25 it will look like this:
[image]

Both doesn't look like as they should when I'm running it on JVM 1.6.0_15 on a 10.6 mac:
[image]

Is there a way to solve this problem? Might the retina resolution be the cause?
This post is kinda related to this one in asked before: [JFrame is lagging on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471675/jframe-is-lagging-on-resize)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can solve this problem by putting the client property as early as possible.

The [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#APPLE_AWT_BRUSHMETALLOOK) says:

> **WARNING:** This property must be set before the heavyweight peer for the Window
>   is created. Once addNotify() has been called on the component, causing
>   creation of the heavyweight peer, changing this property has no
>   effect.

Here is a MWE:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
        frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.brushMetalLook", Boolean.TRUE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of MWE]

If you swap `frame.setVisible(true);` and the part where we put the client property, you get a black frame (Mac OS 10.9.4, Java 1.8.0_05):

[image: Bad example]

Hope, that helped you.